# Will washing child seat belt straps with baking soda and hydrogen peroxide make them unsafe to use?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, cleaning

My friend is afraid to use the child seat for her next child.  She was told washing them with the solution weakened the fabric,  The straps weren't submerged, but they did get throughly wet.

Comment: By peroxide, you mean hydrogen peroxide.

Comment: Yes, hydrogen peroxide.

Comment: @Emily Can you identify the material of the straps, for example glossy _polyester_ (PES) or matt _polyamide_ (symbol: PA and a number)? Polyester is usually resistant to hydrogen peroxide solutions, whereas polyamide will deteriorate.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen some companies that refurbish child seats, perhaps a new strap kit would put your friend's mind at ease.

If the straps were not soaked for hours in concentrated H2O2 and I saw no damage and could not cause them to break with my strength (healthy adult) I would have used it with my kids.  The baking powder or soda should have no effect.

We bought a used seat for the next size up and have no idea of how it was washed.  Would do the same again.

Stay at home, spend the coin, take out a loan or live with the risk, those are the choices. There are other risks in life like not being sure that the excavator operator is of sound mind and will not swing the bucket into your car at the stop sign, does this stop you leaving the house?

**EDIT:**
It is possible the dangers of washing are circulated by the seat refurbishing and manufacturing industries to increase sales and not safety.  A car seatbelt can last for decades and sees a lot more use and has no washing warnings.

Comment: This is not enough evidence that hydrogen peroxide treatment is safe. Also the discussion about attitude to risk is irrelevant and in fact for most parents anything else than zero risk for their children is unacceptable if they can avoid it.

Comment: @K_P your attitude is illogical.  There is NEVER zero risk, getting pregnant has attendant risks, adults and parents especially become adept at weighing risks.  Most parents will agree that they are less neurotic with subsequent children, would you have me believe this is due to them becoming irrational about risk or perhaps an understanding that they were over cautious when less experienced.  Also note my answer covered the risk eliminators profile first to avoid comments like yours, I'll keep trying to educate in a balanced manner in spite of it.